# python code showing wrong output when computing least common multiple for large integers

Tags: python-3.x, greatest-common-divisor, largenumber, lcm

I implemented an lcm problem using the following algorithm in python.
My code is given below :

```
# Uses python3
import sys

def gcd_efficient(a, b):
    #current_gcd = 1
    #for d in range(2, min(a, b) + 1):
    #   if a % d == 0 and b % d == 0:
    #        if d > current_gcd:
    #            current_gcd = d

    #return current_gcd

    remainder = max(a, b) % min(a, b)
    newMax = min(a, b)
    if remainder == 0:
        return newMax

    return  gcd_efficient(newMax, remainder)


def lcm_efficient(a, b):
    #for l in range(1, a*b + 1):
    #   if l % a == 0 and l % b == 0:
    #        return l

    product = a*b
    gcd = gcd_efficient(a, b)
    lcm = product/gcd
    return int(lcm)

print(lcm_efficient(226553150, 1023473145))
```

Now I have used the above code to compute the lcm of large integers being as input.

However I find that for some large integers:
for example, when the input is:
Input:
226553150 1023473145
The output from the python console is: 46374212988031352
But the actual output should be: 46374212988031350

The actual output is differing from the given output by just 2. However, what confuses me is that why is the python interpreter giving errors in output upon executing the above code.

Can this error be nullified?

Waiting for the answers!!

Comment: Python is able to represent large numbers without loss of precision, so that should be fine. The value with the 2 at the end can't be a multiple of the two numbers, because both are multiples of five, so much is clear. Question now is whether your algorithm is wrong. If so, at what point exactly does it fail? I'm aware that this requires a bunch of debugging with large numbers, but I'm afraid there's no help to that.

Comment: I implemented the same algorithm in C++ and it works fine. So I think the algorithm is fairly correct. and if the algorithm was wrong the difference between the actual output and the output given in the console would have been considerable, but here the difference is just 2.

Comment: I believe that a wrong algorithm cannot produce an answer with such a precision as compared to the correct output produced by the correct algorithm.

Comment: Please accept that the issue is *not* with the precision of Python arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
lcm = product/gcd
```

It should be

```
lcm = product//gcd
```

to guarantee integer division. Your translation from C++ assumed that the `/` operator works identically in C++ and Python. And in Python 2 it does. But not in Python 3. In Python 3, `/` calls for *floating point* division, so the original version called for both operands to be converted to floats (losing precision in the process) followed by floating-point division. Your `return` statement converts the floating-point result back to `int`, masking the problem.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `product/gcd` does not convert both operands to floats and then divide those floats (which would involve potentially up to three rounding errors); instead it does the more accurate thing and computes the closest float to the true mathematical quotient. You can see the difference if you compare (for example) `10**40 / 10**39` with `float(10**40) / float(10**39)`, or do `a / b` in a case where both `a` and `b` are too large to be representable as a float (but the quotient is representable).